# Refused entry to Spain previously. Will this affect my Student visa application?

Tags: schengen, spain, study, pakistani-citizens

I am from Pakistan and applied for a Schengen tourist visa for Spain in 2013. The visa was rejected on the grounds the purpose of visit wasn’t clear and that they couldn’t determine whether I would return to my own country, plus that my funds weren’t enough for a visit of two weeks.  I had all the documentation that one could think of, from the invitation letter from a local Spanish resident to the hotel booking, sufficient bank balance ($12,000 for two weeks) and much more.  I appealed the decision instantly and provided them with the invitation letter and still got a refusal stating that my intentions of returning back to my country were not clear. Understandably, I was 23 at that time and I can comprehend their stereotyping process and what not.

Now I will be reapplying for a Student Schengen visa for my master's at a reputable university in Spain, for which I have a 30% scholarship.

Will my earlier rejection affect my Student visa?

My parents will be sponsoring my tuition and living costs. How can I make clear that I am only going for educational purposes and will return to my country?

Comment: I do not have dependents nor any immovable property in Pakistan. Although I can fork around a reasonable bank balance from my parents and on my own. Would the chances still be lower? I can ask my current employer to make me a job offer when I have completed my masters. Any suggestions on how to further improve my chances?

Comment: My history of travel only shows two trips to Dubai in last 7 years (2008 and 2014), I will try to contact a lawyer who has dealt with EU laws and could better assist me. I would like to know whether the universities help by getting in contact with the embassy to give credibility of their students. I was told by the university that the dean is frequently in touch with the embassies regarding their students who are faced with visa issues. What do you think